# Is $\sin \alpha = 2 \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} \cos \frac{\alpha}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Is $\sin \alpha = 2 \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} \cos \frac{\alpha}{2}$?

We know $$\sin 2\alpha = 2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha$$
So,
$$\sin 2 \frac{\alpha}{2}=2 \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}$$

I think I had seen somewhere that.
$$\sin 2 \frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1}{2} \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}$$

If second equation correct than, what I did wrong?

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\sin 2\alpha = 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$. Now, replacing $\alpha$ by $\frac{\alpha}{2}$,

\begin{align*}
    \sin(2\alpha) &= 2 \sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha) \\
    \sin\left(2\cdot\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) &= 2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \\
    \sin\alpha &= 2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

It seems like the equation you are describing suggests that $$\sin(n\alpha) = n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha.$$ No. This is not true. Take $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $n = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the addition theorem:
\begin{align}
\sin(\alpha) 
&= \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \\
&= \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) + 
    \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\\
&= 2 \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) 
\end{align}
Your last equation is simply wrong.